# Animating element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have successfully animated a `div` from bottom to top on window load as fallow:

```
<script>
      $(function(){
          $('#wrapper').animate({'margin-top': '20px'}, 1000);
      });
</script>

#wrapper {
    float: none;
    margin: 600px auto;
    max-width: 850px;
    min-width: 200px;
    padding: 0 2%;
}
```

However, I now need to animate the div from right to left instead.
I tried initial css as:

```
margin-top: 20px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: 100%;
```

and then:

```
<script>
      $(function(){
          $('#wrapper').animate({'margin-left': 'auto'}, 1000);
      });
</script>
```

`auto` doesn't seem to be a valid value, but I need to have the div stop in the center so I tried 
getting width of browser window and then dividing it by two and substracting half of the size
of the wrapper but I couldn't get the width of wrapper as I'm using max-width intead of hardcoding the width. 
I need to keep the site responsive.

How could I accomplish left to right animation having the div stop once it is centered?

Comment: you could use `$('#wrapper').width()` to get its _actual_ width in pixels. That should allow to calculate the center position.

Comment: I tried this but how could I subtract the value from 50%?

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LUgra/3/

Comment: @Arun Thank you, this is close but I still don't get the div centered. It breaks the layout of the site if I don't have it perfectly center.

Comment: @user2300867 do you need it centered vertically also?

Comment: @Arun I don't. margin-top: 20px; works fine. I just need to center it horizontally and animation would be only from right(off screen) to center.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with

```
$("#wrapper").animate({"marginLeft":"50%"}, 1000);
```

Comment: I would get left border of the div at the center of the window.

Comment: intial margin left is 100% and then it would change to 50% which means div will stop once it reach center of the window but not centered which is what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Look at Arun P Johny's answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#wrapper').animate({right: (parseInt($(this).css('right'))-200)+"px"}, 1000);
```